# JqueryMobile Save text field data using save button

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, project

Ive been trying to figure out how to get some data i type into a text field to save on the screen underneath it. Something like a twitter, or Facebook news nothing fancy. I'm using JQM and would like this to get save on the same page as the text field and button under the

```
<div data-role="content">
```

This is what i have for a field and button.

```
<input type="text" id="Text"/>
<input type="button" id="Button" value="Submit" />
<div id="buttonPlaceHolder">&nbsp;</div>
```

and this is some javaScipt i found to go along with the button, it works however the dollar signs screw up JQM and ive tried putting it in its own js file. I think i might be doing something wrong.

```
$('#Button').bind('click', function() {
$('#buttonPlaceHolder').append($('#Text').val());

// refresh jQM controls
$('#home').trigger('create');
});
```

If at all possible id like the javascript in with the html via script

Comment: Have u place this `bind` call in `doucment.ready` ?

Comment: Is your Javascript wrapped under another function ? LIke SJ asked, document.ready or anything else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood the question. Nevertheless try this, it may help:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My Web Page</h1>

<p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>

<p id="myDIV">A DIV.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Hello Dolly";
document.getElementById("myDIV").innerHTML="How are you?";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It is a html page example. You can find more info and useful examples here:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_examples.asp

If you want to save it for later use, try localStorage mechanism.

Comment: Oh yes w3schools i had forgotten about that. Thank you very much i think this will do the trick.